# Why does this work? Assigning a new int value to a pointer after delete

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, memory, dynamic

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main(){
    int *ptr = new int(15);

    cout << "Address of ptr: " << ptr << endl;
    cout << "Content of ptr: " << *ptr << endl << endl;

    delete ptr;
    *ptr = 30;

    cout << "Address of ptr: " << ptr << endl;
    cout << "Content of ptr: " << *ptr << endl;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Address of ptr: 007B81F0
Content of ptr: 15

Address of ptr: 007B81F0
Content of ptr: 30
```

Why does this work? Why can I still use the pointer? What happened?

Is this useful at some point?

Comment: It *doesn't* work. "Work" doesn't mean what you think it does.

Comment: It looks like working code... but it really doesn't. Try to "malloc" some new memory for other resources and your code will overwrite the allocated memory from the other resources. Simply: Your code is "undefined behaviour". All can happen, from "looks like working" to crash.

Comment: Just allocate some more memory before `*ptr = 30;` and try and see what happens.

Comment: This is a good example of [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  In this case, the code is *WRONG*.  It might *appear* to work (in the sense it might not crash on your particular system) ... but that doesn't make it "correct".  And it doesn't necessarily mean it will continue to work on a different system, or in a different context.  Just "don't do it" ;)

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/4342498

Comment: @NathanOliver that answer is one of the best I've ever seen dealing with explaining some concept.

Comment: @vsoftco That answers makes we want to be able to favorite answers just so I can favorite it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is typical undefined behaviour, and it happens to work because the memory that was previously allocated for `*ptr` was not yet reclaimed by the operating system*. You should never rely on this kind of code.

Note that the address of the pointer stays the same, as C++ runtime doesn't bother to nullify the pointer (it takes time and in C++ you don't pay for what you don't need).

<sub>*see also Remy Lebeau's comment below.</sub>

Comment: Also keep in mind that some RTLs cache freed memory for later re-use.  So the memory may still be physically allocated even if it has "logically" been freed. But that is an implementation detail, don't rely on it.  If you `delete` memory, assume you don't have access to it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just as vsoftco explained, the memory was not yet reclaimed by the OS. Now if we do something like below, you may experience a completely different output:

```
int *ptr = new int(15);

cout << "Address of ptr: " << ptr << endl;
cout << "Content of ptr: " << *ptr << endl << endl;
delete ptr;

int *ptr2 = new int(15); // making a new ptr to use memory.
*ptr = 30;               // <- OPS!
delete ptr2;             // deleting new ptr.

cout << "Address of ptr: " << ptr << endl;
cout << "Content of ptr: " << *ptr << endl;
```

Anyway, the result is undefined behaviour

Answer (score -3):

Although delete key word was used but for some reason de-allocation  of pointer did not happen.(Probably scope of the pointer was still in use)

Using pointers is an important aspect of C++.It is important to use pointers to deal at reference level or with memory addresses.